# Copy and rename Specific Files based on parent directories in R

Tags: r, file-rename

I am attempting to solve this issue in R, but I'll upvote answers in any programming language.

I have an example vector of filenames like so called `file_list`

```
c("D:/example/sub1/session1/OD/CD/text.txt", "D:/example/sub2/session1/OD/CD/text.txt", 
"D:/example/sub3/session1/OD/CD/text.txt")
```

What I'm trying to do is move and rename the text files to be based on the part of the parent directory that contains the part about `sub` and `session`. So the first file would be renamed `sub2_session1_text.txt`and be copied along with the other text files to just 1 new directory called `all_files`

I'm struggling with some of the specifics of how to rename the file. I'm trying to use `substr` combined with `str_locate_all` and `paste0` to copy and rename the files based on these parent directories.

Locate the position in each element of the vector `file_list` to construct starting and ending position for `substr`

```
library(stringr)
ending<-str_locate_all(pattern="/OD",file_list)
starting <- str_locate_all(pattern="/sub", file_list)
```

I then want to somehow pull out of those lists the starting and ending position of those patterns for each element and then feed it to `substr` to get the naming down and then in turn use `paste0` to create 
What I'd like is something like

```
substr_naming_vector<-substr(file_list, start=starting[starting_position],stop=ending[starting_position])
```

but I don't know how to index the list such that it can know how to correctly index for each element the `starting_position`. Once I figure that out I'd fill in something like this

```
#paste the filenames into a vector that represents them being renamed in a new directory  
all_files <- paste0("D:/all_files/", substr_naming_vector)
#rename and copy the files 
file.copy(from = file_list, to = all_files)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an example using regular expression, which makes it somewhat shorter:

```r
library(stringr)
library(magrittr)

all_dirs <-
  c("D:/example/sub1/session1/OD/CD/text.txt",
    "D:/example/sub2/session1/OD/CD/text.txt",
    "D:/example/sub3/session1/OD/CD/text.txt")

new_dirs <-
  all_dirs %>%
  # Match each group using regex
  str_match_all("D:/example/(.+)/(.+)/OD/CD/(.+)") %>%
  # Paste the matched groups into one path
  vapply(function(x) paste0(x[2:4], collapse = "_"), character(1)) %>%
  paste0("D:/all_files/", .)

# Copy them.
file.copy(all_dirs, new_dirs)
```

Comment: This worked great! Out of curiosity, how could you adjust the regex `(.+)"` such that it could select specific files with patterns inside? for example, if I only wanted the text files that had either the words "bear" OR "dog" how would I adjust the regex to represent that?

Comment: Suppose that instead of `sub1`, `sub2`, etc.. you wanted to match specifically `dog1`, `dog2`, etc.. then `D:/example/(dog[0-9])/(.+)/OD/CD/(.+)` could do it. Another example for the **name** of the life: `D:/example/(.+)/(.+)/OD/CD/dog[0-9].txt`

Answer (score 2):

This is one way of doing it. I assumed your file is always called `text.txt`.

```
library(stringr)

my_files <- c("D:/example/sub1/session1/OD/CD/text.txt",
              "D:/example/sub2/session1/OD/CD/text.txt", 
              "D:/example/sub3/session1/OD/CD/text.txt")

# get the sub information
subs <- str_extract(string = my_files,
                    pattern = "sub[0-9]")
# get the session information
sessions <- str_extract(string = my_files,
                        pattern = "session[0-9]")

# paste it all together
new_file_names <- paste("D:/all_files/", 
                        paste(subs, 
                              sessions, 
                              "text.txt",
                              sep = "_"),
                  sep = "")

file.copy(from = my_files, 
          to = new_file_names)
```