# Renaming files based on parent directories with specific file names in R

Tags: r, regex

this is a follow up from previous thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59387013/copy-and-rename-specific-files-based-on-parent-directories-in-r). I have the same goal, but with a slight adjustment.

So assuming a new vector of filenames

```
c("D:/example/sub1/session1/OD/CD/adsfadfadsfadfadf_blue.txt", "D:/example/sub2/session1/OD/CD/text.txt", 
"D:/example/sub3/session1/OD/CD/text.txt")
```

How would I adjust this code

```
library(stringr)
library(magrittr)

all_dirs <-
  c("D:/example/sub1/session1/OD/CD/text.txt",
    "D:/example/sub2/session1/OD/CD/text.txt",
    "D:/example/sub3/session1/OD/CD/text.txt")

new_dirs <-
  all_dirs %>%
  # Match each group using regex
  str_match_all("D:/example/(.+)/(.+)/OD/CD/(.+)") %>%
  # Paste the matched groups into one path
  vapply(function(x) paste0(x[2:4], collapse = "_"), character(1)) %>%
  paste0("D:/all_files/", .)

# Copy them.
file.copy(all_dirs, new_dirs)
```

such that I can select only the files that have `blue` somewhere in the filename? I had tried adjusting this line

```
str_match_all("D:/example/(.+)/(.+)/OD/CD/(.+)") %>%
```

to instead say

```
str_match_all("D:/example/(.+)/(.+)/OD/CD/*blue*") %>%
```

but that didn't seem to work. Also, the main goal remains the same as the previous post. I want the full filename to be retained.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry I don't know R, but how about:

```
str_match_all("D:/example/(.+)/(.+)/OD/CD/(.*blue[^/]*)") %>%
```

If the regex in R behaves like in other engines/languages, then the .+ will match one or more of any character.  So potentially might match multiple levels in the directory hierarchy.  The .* will match zero or more of any character.  The [^/]* will match zero or more of any character that is not a slash.

I hope this helps ... you might wish to change all your .+ or .* to [^/]+ or [^/]* if you want to restrict that section of the URL to one directory level.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `grep` to filter the values first and then continue the same approach

```
new_dirs <- grep('blue', all_dirs, value = TRUE) %>%
               stringr::str_match_all("D:/example/(.+)/(.+)/OD/CD/(.+)") %>%
               vapply(function(x) paste0(x[2:4], collapse = "_"), character(1)) %>%
               paste0("D:/all_files/", .)

new_dirs
 #[1] "D:/all_files/sub1_session1_adsfadfadsfadfadf_blue.txt"
```

**data**

```
all_dirs <- c("D:/example/sub1/session1/OD/CD/adsfadfadsfadfadf_blue.txt", 
              "D:/example/sub2/session1/OD/CD/text.txt", 
              "D:/example/sub3/session1/OD/CD/text.txt")
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be another solution.

Fellowing original request modifing the pattern .

Then , turning "*blue*" to "(.*blue.*)".

"*blue*" means the aim texts are getting the file name which only contain "blue" .

"(.*blue.*)" means the four type  target string .

There are four examples .

1. only  "blue" .
2. "bluewud"  .
3. "Dhublue"  .
4. "Dueblue72yd"  .

```
new_dirs <-
  all_dirs %>%
  # Match each group using regex
  str_match_all("D:/example/(.+)/(.+)/OD/CD/(.*blue.*)") %>%  
# Paste the matched groups into one path
  vapply(function(x){paste0(x[2:4], collapse = "_")%>%paste0(x[1],.)},character(1)) %>% 
  grep(pattern = "D:",value = T)
```